# iOS system data

Tags: iphone, ios, filesystems, system

I am developing an application where I need to know some of my iphone system information such as the cpu speed and above the list of processes in memory and the system log.
I have seen on AppleStore that there are some apps (Apple-approved) that display the data (Ex JustSys) then it means that Apple provides tools for information system of this type.
I tried searching on the net but could not find anything. Does anyone know how to get this info?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at below link. Might be helpful for you

1. http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2009/01/source-code-get-hardware-info-of-iphone.html